# How to schedule jobs in PHP in linux using CRON jobs or others?

Tags: php, cron, job-scheduling, cron-task

I'm trying to schedule the jobs in PHP but I didn't find any way to do that. I tried to use PHPJobScheduler but I couldn't do that. Plase help me do that.

Comment: Are you using any php framework?

Comment: No, I'm using Core PHP Only

Comment: You should learn more about what is CRON Job and what it is used for. (refer : http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ crontab -e
```

Then edit your cronjobs. For example, you add new job like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/do/script.php
```

then your php jobs be work.

Comment: Thanks Deep, But how will I create jobs from php? I need to create different kinds of reminders.

Comment: @vishgarg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php